# Android Flutter Firebase Phone Auth Not Working

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, authentication

I am struggling to get a successful Phone verification on Android with Flutter. (it's working on iOS, it was already working on Android a couple of months ago and it is still working with Test-Phone-Numbers / Codes which are generated in Firebase)

Current Setup:
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.2
firebase_core: ^2.13.1
firebase_analytics: ^10.4.2
firebase_auth: ^4.6.2
firebase_performance: ^0.9.2+2
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.15
firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.8.0

- Authentication activated in Firebase
- SHA-1 and SHA-256 added in Firebase
- google-services.json added in Flutter project
- SHA-1 added to API-Key in console.cloud.google
- PhoneNumber entered -> Code sent&received -> Verification fails

Could this have anything to do with App-Integrity, App-Signature or settings in console.cloud.google?

- The setUp was done via the guidelines of google (its working on iOS, so code is working)
- SHA were checked multiple times if correctly added
- Tested via Test-Phone-Numbers (working)

Result after following flow: PhoneNumber entered -> Code sent&received -> Verification fails (Installation not via Play Store, however via Play Store it isn't working neither)

```
I/zzf     (22771): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = false, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=<nonce>, cloudProjectNumber=<cloudProjectNumber>})
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(22771): The input method toggled cursor monitoring off
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore(22771): UID: [10187]  PID: [22771] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/System  (22771): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats(22771): tagSocket(70) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
E/FirebaseAuth(22771): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
D/FirebaseAuth(22771): Re-triggering phone verification with Recaptcha flow forced for phone number <number>
I/zzf     (22771): ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = true, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
W/System  (22771): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/Parcel  (22771): Expecting binder but got null!
E/OpenGLRenderer(22771): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
E/OpenGLRenderer(22771): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
E/OpenGLRenderer(22771): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
E/zzf     (22771): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an internal error in the web widget. [ {"code":"auth/internal-error","message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"domain\":\"global\",\"reason\":\"forbidden\"}],\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"details\":[{\"@type\":\"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo\",\"reason\":\"API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED\",\"domain\":\"googleapis.com\",\"metadata\":{\"service\":\"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com\",\"consumer\":\"projects/<number>\"}}]}}"} ]]- calling backend without app verification
W/System  (22771): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth(22771): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 nulltype here
```

Thanks in advance, we are desperately looking for this error for a long time now, hopefully someone with more experience can help!

Comment: Update which hopefully saves other people some time: Make sure that the timeout parameter of the verifyPhoneNumber - Method is set high enough. After setting this parameter to 10 seconds or higher everything was working again.